# How can I save .mat data from twincat?

Tags: matlab, simulink, twincat

I am using the below model for real-time control with twincat. I cannot get the .mat file in the folder. In the twincat environment, I have linked the object to the `tcextendedfilewriter`. I can obtain data from the workspace, but I cannot save data from twincat in external mode.

How can I save .mat files from twincat directly in external mode?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you use TwinCAT3 Target for Simulink, you can set up the `TcExtendedFileWriter` according to the [manual](https://download.beckhoff.com/download/Document/automation/twincat3/TE1400_TC3_Target_Matlab_EN.pdf) by Beckhoff. Section 8.4 covers using the "ToFile" block.

Make sure that you're checking the **correct path**: The .mat file will be created on the runtime PC, not the development PC.

Also, note that the `TcExtendedFilewriter` object has a **Pause input**, which you need to set to `FALSE` to enable logging.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)